# PHP OOP Query Does Not Insert a New Row Into DB

Tags: php, mysql, oop

I'm working on a custom CMS using PHP OOP and now I have faced a really bad issue ! Basically I have a form like this:

```
<form role="form" method="POST" action="">
    <div class="box-body">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Menu name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter menu name" name="mname" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Menu link numbers</label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Number of menu items" min="1" max="9" name="mnumbers" required>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box-footer">
        <button name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

And as the action I coded this:

```
    <?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $menu_name      = $_POST['mname'];
    $menu_numbers   = $_POST['mnumbers'];
    $nav = new Navigation();
    $nav->NewMenu($menu_name,$menu_numbers);
}
?>
```

So as you can see I have called a class named `Navigation`. This class goes like this:

```
    <?php 
class Navigation
{
    private $db;
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->db = new Connection();
        $this->db = $this->db->dbConnect();
    }
    public function NewMenu($menu_name,$menu_numbers)
    {
        if(!empty($menu_name)&&!empty($menu_numbers))
        {
            $ins = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO menu_nav (menu_name, menu_items) VALUES ('?', '?')");
            $ins->bindParam(1,$menu_name);
            $ins->bindParam(2,$menu_numbers);
            $ins->execute();
        }else{
            header("Location: maint/php/includes/errors/009.php");
            exit();
        }
    }
}
?>
```

So everything looks great and the data must be inserted to the table but the problem is that ,whenever I run this code nothing added into the db except the ? mark and zero number !

[image: Here's the print screen of my MySQL database]

So what's going wrong here, can someone tell me what's the problem ?

Comment: When will you learn to read manuals? `'?'` is not a placeholder, it's s string with __one symbol__ - `?`.

Comment: closing as a typo.

Comment: What does this do in the query - INSERT INTO menu_nav (menu_name, menu_items) VALUES ('?', '?')?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `INSERT` statement won't be prepared for binding. Just remove the `'` before and after the `?`s. Like so:

```
$ins = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO menu_nav (menu_name, menu_items) VALUES (?, ?)");
                                                                                ^  ^
```